# C# QuickSort recursive program not sorting

Tags: c#, wpf, arrays, collections, quicksort

I am trying to understand a quicksort example. I randomly generate 9 numbers and place in a list. The program selects a random pivot. Based on the pivot, the other values in the list are placed into the left list or right list. Then I call the method again using left list and right. This is where I get confused. It doesn't completely sort the 9 numbers. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my updated code. Now, if a pivot number is the same as another number in the list, it is not included in the sorted list when return e.g. unsorted 487878146, sorted 14678
The piece of code that I think is causing the issue is (if (j == pivot) continue;)

```
public static List<int> QuickSort(List<int> arr)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int i, pivot;

        List<int> leftList = new List<int>();
        List<int> rightList = new List<int>();

        if (arr.Count > 1)
        {
            //pivot = random.Next(arr[0],arr[arr.Count - 1]);
            pivot = arr[random.Next(0, arr.Count - 1)];
                foreach(int j in arr)
                {
                    if (j == pivot) continue;
                    if (j <= pivot)
                        leftList.Add(j);
                    else
                        rightList.Add(j);
                }

            List<int> sortedLeft = QuickSort(leftList);
            List<int> sortedRight = QuickSort(rightList);

            List<int> tempList = new List<int>();
            tempList.AddRange(sortedLeft);
            tempList.Add(pivot);
            tempList.AddRange(sortedRight);

            //for (i = 1; i <= leftList.Count; i++)
            //    tempList.Add(leftList[i - 1]);
            //tempList.Add(pivot);
            //for (i = 1; i <= rightList.Count; i++)
            //    tempList.Add(rightList[i - 1]);


            return tempList;
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

Comment: You should not create multiple `Random` objects. Create one and reuse it. Though here it is probably not related to your actual problem.

Comment: Please debug your code yourself first... There was also solution to the same problem earlier today to compare - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785824/what-am-i-doing-wrong-in-this-c-sharp-quicksort-algorithm

Comment: this doesn't really look like quicksort at all.  This looks like mergesort but without the merge, and not quite cutting each segment exactly in half.

Comment: Also, isn't the one of the strong points of quicksort being able to sort in place, rather than using temporary lists?

Comment: Your selection of the pivot won't always be an item in the list.  Rather than a random number between max and min, take a random index between 0 and the list size and use the item at that index. (or, for simplicity, just use the first item).

Answer (score 2):

Your quicksort returns the sorted list, so you need to merge them instead of the unsorted inputs:

```
List<int> sortedLeft = QuickSort(leftList);
List<int> sortedRight QuickSort(rightList);

List<int> tempList = new List<int>();
tempList.AddRange(sortedLeft);
tempList.Add(pivot);
tempList.AddRange(sortedRight);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Lee's answer, you should modify your pivot selection because you are using random number that doesn't have to be in the array and then insert it in a list. You can try for instance something like this:

```
pivot = arr[random.Next(0,arr.Length - 1)];
```

Comment: Thanks,I updated my code. Now, if a pivot number is the same as another number in the list, it is not included in the sorted list when returned e.g. unsorted 487878146, sorted 14678 The piece of code that I think is causing the issue is (if (j == pivot) continue;)

Comment: Yes,but you can include j element in any list you want. For instance,instead of continue,put in a leftList.

Comment: I tried and got a StackOverflow exception. What I did was count the amount of times the j element is equal to the pivot. Then when I merge the lists, I add the pivot, n amount of times to the list based on the count. It works.